# print number with comma as hundred separator

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a number like "7847258998" which I want to print with hundred comma separator in javascript.
The result should be:

```
7,84,72,58,998
```

i.e the first three digits from right should be grouped together. Remaining digits grouped in chunks of 2. I tried with following:

```
"7847258998".replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
```

But it returns: `7,8,4,72,58998`. What is the right expression?

Comment: Made it work. I Separated last 3 digits and applied comma on the remaining using `(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",")`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
"7847258998".replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})*(\d{3})$)/g, ",");
```

I match the end of the string in the lookahead so that I'm always looking for something sane.  Otherwise just about anything matches.

Tested on inputs length 1-10..  Enough to decide that it probably works.  Pretty inefficient way to do it though, as for each character you have to parse the rest of the string.

But you *did* ask for a regular expression that does the job =)

Comment: +1. As a small improvement, you might change `\B` to `\d`, and the replacement-string from `","` to `"$1,"`. That way, it will only insert a comma after a digit specifically (and not after a letter or underscore).

Comment: Not sure if its that inefficient, as it is voted as the best answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
function commafy(num)
{  
   num  =  num+"";  
   var  re=/(-?\d+)(\d{3})/  
   while(re.test(num))
   {  
     num=num.replace(re,"$1,$2")  
   }  
   return  num;  
}
function  commafyback(num)
{  
   var x = num.split(',');
   return parseFloat(x.join(""));
} 
alert(commafy(7847258998))
```

Comment: That gives the wrong answer: it gives `7,847,258,998`, but the OP wants `7,84,72,58,998`. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Asian_numbering_system.)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the number to a locale string using the `en-IN` locale.

```js
(7847258998).toLocaleString("en-IN")
```

If the value is a string, convert it to a number first:

```
const value = "7847258998"
Number(value).toLocaleString("en-IN")
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString